# Calculus operation of dy/dx

Tags: calculus

I found the following operation: With $v$ is velocity, $t$ is time and $x$ is distance:

$dv/dt= (dv/dt)(dx/dx)= (dv/dx)(dx/dt)= (dv/dx)v= d/dx(v^2/2)$

Just wondering how to come up with the last line. Thanks.

Comment: This forum should have the option allowing to see the ID of of those smart pants downgrading the original posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the last equality you just need to include $v$ in the derivative, and the way to do it is

\begin{align}
\frac{}{}=\frac{}{}(\int v\frac{}{})=\frac{}{}(\int)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{}{}(^{2})
\end{align}

Comment: I don't know how to pose the question in any better way. d/dx(v^2) = 2v (dv/dx) I get that. But look at what is in the last line in the OP. Thanks.

Comment: The "last line" in your original post is "$(d/dx)v^2= 2v dv/dx$.  You should have learned that $(d/dv)v^2= 2v$ in the first few weeks, if not days, of Calculus.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly your doubt, but take it this way: $v\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(\int v\frac{dv}{dx}dx)=\frac{d}{dx}(\int vdv)= \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{v^{2}}{2})$

Comment: @user247327 the last line is not what you have stated, it is (/)(^2)/2.

Comment: @N.Sobrino, that's it! Could you please update your answer with the manipulation you did in your last comment? I would like to take that as the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply either the product rule or the chain rule. For example $\frac d {dx} v^{2}=\frac d {dx} (v)(v)=v(\frac d {dx} v)+(\frac d {dx} v) v=2v(\frac d {dx} v)$. Now divide by $2$.

Comment: How do you divide by 2 just like that? I'm aware of product or chain rule but not sure how in the OP, "divided by 2" appears. Thanks.